# Mysql WorkBench : Default varchar value as empty

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Before I started using MySql WorkBench, I was using phpmyadmin and liked to set default values of varchars to empty. So in my code I would not have to check for null values and could only use if $value = '' comparisions. How do I put default value as empty in mysql workbench? If i leave the text box empty unlike phpmyadmin it thinks I do not want any default value.

Thanking you

Imran

Comment: This is an irritating bug!  I have confirmed your comment to peterm's answer does not actually have an effect on the table, due to MySQL Workbench responding "No changes detected".
Funny side note: our SO rep was within 2 points of eachother (1446, 1444) until I voted you up.

Comment: Interesting how this still isn't fixed with the latest release. Someone should post a bug report

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Just put two quotes `''` in `default` field for your column.

[image: Assigning an empty string as a default value in MySql Workbench]

Or right-click on a column and choose `Default ''`

[image: Assigning an empty string as a default value from context menu in MySql Workbench]

Comment: right click option not working. click and nothing happens. bug maybe. manually doing fixed it.

Comment: @ImranOmarBukhsh +1 for the answer not working.  MySQL Workbench bug.  Must alter table manually using SQL

Answer (score 5):

The workbench has a bug an fails to update the empty string (it says, no changes).
I set it to a space first ' ', and then change the sql code to an empty string ''.  That does the trick.